# 3-regular (cubic) graph with adjacency eigenvalue 1

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ is the adjacency matrix of a 3-regular (cubic) graph $G=(V,E)$; that is, all $n$ vertices $v\in V$ in the graph have three neighbors.

Is there a nice necessary condition for $A$ to have eigenvalue $\lambda=1$?  E.g., does this somehow restrict the topology of $G$ (bipartite, colorable, etc.)?

Equivalently, since $L=3I-A$ in this case, when can the graph Laplacian have eigenvalue 2?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of nice condition you're hoping for.  As an example, consider a (not 3-regular) graph $G$ constructed as follows: There are $8$ vertices $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, a,b,c,d$.  The edges consist of the $4$-cycles $x_1, a, y_1, b$ and $x_2, c, y_2, d$, together with edges $(x_1, x_2)$ and $(y_1, y_2)$ (This graph can also be thought of as the $3$ dimensional hypercube minus two opposite edges).  This graph is bipartite, but any $3$-regular graph containing it as a subgraph has a $1$  eigenvalue (with eigenvector $1$ on $x_1$ and $x_2$, $-1$ on $y_1$ and $y_2$, and $0$ elsewhere).

Comment: (continued) so the graph can be as nice/ugly as you want elsewhere, but as long as it satisfies this local condition, it'll have $1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Kevin's construction is very nice. One can construct cubic graphs with eigenvalue 1 also by taking two disjoint copies of a 2-regular graph and adding a perfect matching between them. The eigenvalues of the resulting cubic graph will be $\lambda\pm 1$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the $2$-regular graph used. I suspect there are other ways to build cubic graphs with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Too bad, it appears it's not a nice problem!  In reality, I have a closed triangulated surface without boundary and am looking at the adjacency graph of the triangles (node in the graph for each triangle, two nodes are adjacent if they share an edge in the triangulation).  These constructions still work but seem like rarities for a "general" surface.  Hmmm!